# My .NET process terminates with exit code -1

Tags: .net, debugging, crash

I have a process that I run as a console application under my account on an environment where I do not have Visual Studio. Sometimes it just terminates with the exit code of -1.

I installed procdump as AeDebug to no avail - no dump is created! I am certain that procdump is installed correctly, because a dummy application running in exactly the same way does produce a dump when told to crash (it writes to 0 using native code).

Moreover, I ran the application from within cdb (with `sxd av;sxd *;g`) and it dies too. No exception message. The last messages in the debugger are boring ModLoad messages.

The application logs a lot, but the termination occurs at different point every time, so the logs are not helpful.

There is nothing in the event manager.

I am at a complete loss here. What to do next?

Answer (score 1):

The AeDebugger only kicks in in certain circumstances. If the application handles the exception and exits, the AEDebugger doesn't start.

You can use the -t switch to dump your application when it terminates.
Or use the -e or -e 1 switches to create dumps on exceptions or first chance exceptions.